# How to stop product images being displayed

Tags: magento-1.9, image, css, store-view, html

I want to sell my services through a Magento store. I don't have any pictures of my services to add in store so in simple words. I just want to make an store without any product image.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to remove all product images

Comment: Yes I want to remove all product images and make the store without any product images.

Comment: I tried not to upload any image when I am adding any product but in the frontend its automatically showing magento logo instead of removing that whole image frame from product page

Comment: approximately how many products you have

Comment: Products are 100+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in a seperate file in your root folder and run this,

```
<?php
      require_once 'app/Mage.php';
      Mage::app();
      Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
      $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
      $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");

      foreach($products as $product) 
      {
       $prodID = $product->getId();
       $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);
       $items = $mediaApi->items($_product->getId());
       foreach($items as $item) 
       {
        $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(), $item['file']);
       }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Where should I run this code?

Comment: place this in your root folder and run this. If any doubt, ask me

Comment: Ok. I hope this will not hurt my site

Comment: its giving me this error
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /home/site/public_html/image.php on line 6

Comment: i am getting the same error.

Comment: I changed the code. Check it now. I run this code in my local,it will remove all products images.

Comment: code works this time and deletes all images from my magento store but please click on the link to understand my exact problem. http://oi60.tinypic.com/15i52zc.jpg

Comment: step 1:                                                  Find the below code  and remove in
frontend/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

    <div class="product-img-box">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media')   ?>   </div>                                                       Step:2 Change the css from float:right to float: right for class="product-shop"

Comment: saravanavelu. your are the champ :)  my problem solved. i just wanna give special thanks to you. thanks for your great support. thanks again :)